# Getting error on null and empty string while copying a csv file from blob container to Azure SQL DB

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-blob-storage

I tried all combination on the datatype of my data but each time my data factory pipeline is giving me this error:

{
    "errorCode": "2200",
    "message": "ErrorCode=UserErrorColumnNameNotAllowNull,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Empty or Null string found in Column Name 2. Please make sure column name not null and try again.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common,'",
    "failureType": "UserError",
    "target": "xxx",
    "details": []
}

My Copy data source code is something like this:`{
    "name": "xxx",
    "description": "uuu",
    "type": "Copy",
    "dependsOn": [],
    "policy": {
        "timeout": "7.00:00:00",
        "retry": 0,
        "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
        "secureOutput": false,
        "secureInput": false
    },
    "userProperties": [],
    "typeProperties": {
        "source": {
            "type": "DelimitedTextSource",
            "storeSettings": {
                "type": "AzureBlobStorageReadSettings",
                "recursive": true,
                "wildcardFileName": "*"
            },
            "formatSettings": {
                "type": "DelimitedTextReadSettings"
            }
        },
        "sink": {
            "type": "AzureSqlSink"
        },
        "enableStaging": false,
        "translator": {
            "type": "TabularTranslator",
            "mappings": [
                {
                    "source": {
                        "name": "populationId",
                        "type": "Guid"
                    },
                    "sink": {
                        "name": "PopulationID",
                        "type": "String"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "source": {
                        "name": "inputTime",
                        "type": "DateTime"
                    },
                    "sink": {
                        "name": "inputTime",
                        "type": "DateTime"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "source": {
                        "name": "inputCount",
                        "type": "Decimal"
                    },
                    "sink": {
                        "name": "inputCount",
                        "type": "Decimal"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "source": {
                        "name": "inputBiomass",
                        "type": "Decimal"
                    },
                    "sink": {
                        "name": "inputBiomass",
                        "type": "Decimal"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "source": {
                        "name": "inputNumber",
                        "type": "Decimal"
                    },
                    "sink": {
                        "name": "inputNumber",
                        "type": "Decimal"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "source": {
                        "name": "utcOffset",
                        "type": "String"
                    },
                    "sink": {
                        "name": "utcOffset",
                        "type": "Int32"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "source": {
                        "name": "fishGroupName",
                        "type": "String"
                    },
                    "sink": {
                        "name": "fishgroupname",
                        "type": "String"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "source": {
                        "name": "yearClass",
                        "type": "String"
                    },
                    "sink": {
                        "name": "yearclass",
                        "type": "String"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "inputs": [
        {
            "referenceName": "DelimitedTextFTDimensions",
            "type": "DatasetReference"
        }
    ],
    "outputs": [
        {
            "referenceName": "AzureSqlTable1",
            "type": "DatasetReference"
        }
    ]
}`
Can anyone please help me understand the issue. I see in some blogs they ask me use treatnullasempty but I am not allowed to modify the JSON. is there a way to do that??

Comment: Did you mean there null values of in column 2 in CSV file? Can you show us piece of your source dataset?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed it.it was a easy fix as one of my column in destination was marked as not null, i changed it as null and it worked.

Comment: You can accept(mark) it as answer. This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to using [Data Flow DerivedColumn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-derived-column), DerivedColumn can help you build expression to replace the null column.

For example:
[image]

Derived Column, if `Column_2` is null =`true`, return 'dd' :

```
iifNull(Column_2,'dd')
```

[image]
[image]

Mapping the column
[image]

Reference: [Data transformation expressions in mapping data flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-expression-functions)

Hope this helps.